# Using Nested Loop

Tags: for-loop, xquery

Code for nested loop:

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $message := (1, 2)
for $s in $message
    let $message1 := count($message)
    for $i in ((1 to $message1))

        return 
            <results>
                <count>{$i}</count>
            </results>
```

By using this nested for loop, i'm getting this sequence double. So how to get the result for single time by using Nested loop.

Comment: any chances of using nested loop to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're using a loop in the first place. If you just want the message count:

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $message := (1, 2)
let $i := count( $message )

return 
    <results>
        <count>{$i}</count>
    </results>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
  for $i in 1 to count($message)
    return 
        <results>
            <count>{$i}</count>
        </results>
```

**Explanation**:

The duplication resulting from the original code is due to this:

```
for $s in $message
```

Because `$message` is a sequence with two items, the body of the `for` expression is executed twice. This inner `for` isn't necessary as the variable `$s` isn't referenced at all in the body of this `for` expression.